# How to change a licence key in anaconda for a software

Tags: python, linux, macos, unix

I have installed a software I want to be using but I am not able to edit the licence key for some reason. 
After the install it says this: 
    Edit //anaconda/lib/modeller-9.17/modlib/modeller/config.py
    and replace XXXX with your Modeller license key
    (or set the KEY_MODELLER environment variable before running 'conda   install').

Now when I copy //anaconda/lib/modeller-9.17/modlib/modeller/config.py into my shell, I get a message permission denied. 
Can anybody help? Also, how would I go about setting the environment? 
Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the MODELLER license key (which you need to install and run MODELLER) please fill out the following License Agreement:
https://salilab.org/modeller/registration.html

Answer (score 0):

For installation of Modeller in anaconda, you can set environment variable for license before installation. Then follow as bellow:

```
conda config --add channels salilab

export KEY_MODELLER=XXX

conda install modeller
```

consider that instead of XXX, you should type the registration key that you received from https://salilab.org/modeller/registration.html by your academic mail. Hope it works for you...